# Windows Upgrade April 2017 Broke VirtualBox 5.0

Tags: virtualbox, windows-update, laravel-4.2

This is in case anyone else has this issue.  After Microsoft's April 2017 upgrade, my VirtualBox running Laravel 4.2 stopped working.  I found this in my event log files:

Faulting application name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 5.0.26.8824, time stamp: 0x578cc301
Faulting module name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 5.0.26.8824, time stamp: 0x578cc301
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000139ed
Faulting process id: 0x2ca8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2ba0aeebae4e7
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Report Id: 4632a9fe-85d8-4f5b-8feb-f5079407f195
Faulting package full name:

Answer (score 1):

I searched the internet and found other people had this issue with previous Microsoft Updates.  They recommended reinstalling VirtualBox.  I tried it and it resolved my issue.  I reinstalled with the latest 5.0 version.  The latest 5.1 version did not work since my framework was made for 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed:  Uninstalling and re-installing fixes this issue for me also.  Was on 5.0.26 but re-installed 5.0.40 with upgraded extension pack and all VM's worked fine.